# Buffer inside (b)Table

Tags: context

```
\starttext
\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD%
    \startbuffer[mytest]
    \input knuth
    \stopbuffer[mytest]
\eTD \eTR%
\eTABLE%
\stoptext
```

```
tex error    > tex error on line 10 in file ...tex: ! Undefined control sequence
```

Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: The answer is probably along the lines of "because tables use buffers", but nested tables work fine and I've seen an xtable example within a buffer.

Comment: The answer is “because Natural Tables don't use buffers”

Comment: I suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you elaborate on how you plan to use the contents of the buffer?

Comment: @Aditya See [Framed and Interline space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536361/174577) for the most current incarnation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't do it.  Put the buffer outside the table.

---

The reason is that `\bTD...\eTD` reads the content in between as an argument.  You can easily reproduce the same error with this:

```
\starttext
\def\test#1\endtest{#1}
\test
    \startbuffer[mytest]
    \input knuth
    \stopbuffer[mytest]
\endtest
\stoptext
```

The actual problem is that by reading the content as an argument, catcodes are being fixed, in particular, line endings are converted to spaces, which results in

```
\test \startbuffer[mytest] \input knuth \stopbuffer[mytest] \endtest
```

but both `\startbuffer` and `\stopbuffer` have to appear on an individual line.

Deeper down, `\start...\stopbuffer` uses the `process_input_buffer` callback to scan the buffer, but when you register the callback on the line where `\startbuffer` appears, it will only kick in *on the next line*, i.e. everything else on the same line as `\startbuffer` is still normally processed and expanded by TeX.  The `\stopbuffer` command is not actually defined because it is only used as a marker for the callback to know when to stop scanning and is then discarded, but because it appears as regular TeX input here and it is not defined, you get the undefined control sequence error you are seeing.

---

Since you keep insisting that for some unknown, ludicrous reason you *have* to do this, here is a poor workaround that is guaranteed to fail in other cases.  I strongly believe that buffers are the wrong way to do whatever you want to do, but since you keep making up [XY problems](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean) (which you have been repeatedly asked not to) there is really nothing further I can do.

**The real solution is to *not use buffers in macros*.  Neither as an argument, nor in the replacement text.**

```
\starttext
\def\test#1\endtest{#1}
\test
    \ctxlua{buffers.assign(
        "mytest",
        "\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{\input knuth }}")}%
\endtest
\getbuffer[mytest]
\stoptext
```

Comment: You get the same error when the buffer is inside the body, not as an argument. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: @user19087 I've edited my answer.

Comment: Whenever I post the X to an XY problem I'm told its too open-ended. For which I apologize but will try to boil down: What I really need to do is pass a block of TeX to Lua from within a macro. The block includes some TeX provided by the macro and some  TeX provided by its argument. The argument should not be expanded (verbatim). The macro is non-negotiable. The hierarchy: `\def -> \framed -> Lua -> \framed -> #1`. I *thought* buffer would be the only solution, but then realized I don't really know how `\def\test#1\endtest{#1}` works and if it could be applied.

Comment: @user19087 I don't see why you need a buffer for that.  What's wrong with `\def\test#1\endtest{\ctxlua{whatever("\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{#1}}")}}`?

Comment: Hmm, nothing as far as I can tell. However if Lua will pass the argument unmodified back to TeX, is the buffer approach more prone to failure? In terms of reliability what is the difference between `\ctxlua{whateverlua("\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{#1}}")} ... function whateverlua(a) context.whatevertex(a) end` and `\ctxlua{buffers.assign("mytest","\luaescapestring{\normalunexpanded{#1}}")} ... \def\whatevertex{\getbuffer[mytest]}`